# WCF: Choosing between increasing maximum array length and splitting the message into smaller packages

Tags: wcf, binding, partitioning, large-data

*Side note: even if the question was posted several months ago, I'm still in search of a good answer so any feedback is welcomed.*

While developing WCF Web Services I have encountered the error:

`The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data.`

like many others and have solved it by modifying the binding configuration.

When looking for answers on the Internet, the solution was almost always changing the binding configuration, setting the `maxArrayLength` to maximum, going to `Streamed` transfer.
In some situations, like in this question [WCF sending huge data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674830/wcf-sending-huge-data) , people suggest modifying the binding configuration over transmiting data in smaller chunks.

But the maximum values and streamed transfer will always work? Even in a system where you may never know what maximum size will have the data?

How to choose between the two options?

It depends on what you transfer? Downloading media vs. returning large log information?

The answer given to me until now revolves around technical aspects of streaming, but **the answer I am looking for should be more focused on guidelines in the situation exposed, about choosing between the two options**.

Answer (score 1):

Not all bindings support streaming. The only ones that do are basicHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding,  NetNamedPipeBinding, and WebHttpBinding.  You also do not get to do reliable sessions if using  streaming.

So why the big deal about streaming for large messages?  Well if you don't use streaming, it is going to load the entire message in the memory buffer which can kill the available resources.

For more information, see this on MSDN: [MSDN Large Message Transfers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and link; I will study the MSDN documentation for further understanting.